# Which event raise on cell value change in Infragistics UltraGrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using Infragistics UltraGrid in a Windows Forms application.
I need an event which is raised on cell value change.
I've tried many events like `AfterCellActivate`, `AfterCellUpdate` but was unable to find the right one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AfterCellUpdate is what you want, but you may need to call:

- YourGridControl.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
- YourGridControl.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode)

to actually trigger the update, depending on when you want it triggered.

I've noticed that it can sometimes be finicky on when it'll fire off the event, otherwise.

Comment: It triggers after the cell 'loses focus' and the contents are validated.

Comment: Right. But if he's wanting an immediate response to a cell being changed (like a checkbox being clicked), he'll need to call PerformAction via code.

Comment: Haha, I already thought it was weird to see 2 Infragistics questions in such a short timespan :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a CellChange event which fires when the user begins to type a value in the cell.  This event is useful if you need to know exactly when a cell is modified as the AfterCellUpdate event only fires when the user exits from the cell s/he is changing.

Answer (score 1):

AfterCellUpdate should be the right event...
Make sure the event is enabled in the EventManager!